# Difference between creating foreign key and 1 to 1 identifying relationship in MySQL Workbench

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am drawing up an ER model for a to-be application using MySQL workbench.
Being new to MySQL workbench, just wanted to understand how creating a foreign-key and 1-to-1 identifying relationship are different

```
Table: Employee
Column1: EmployeeID, Type INT [Primary Key]
Column2: Name, Type Varchar(45)

Table: EmployeeDetails
Column1: EmployeeID, Type INT [Primary Key]
Column2: Address, Varchar(100)
```

If I create a foreign key on EmployeeDetails table employeeid column that references employee table EmployeeID column, how is it different than creating a 1-to-1 identifying relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys and relationships are the same concept, just from different views. FKs are the entitity used in the database while relationships are their visualization in a model. In your model you only create relationships. You can edit their properties in the relationship editor (e.g. by double clicking on a relationship) to be 1:1, 1:n, identifying or not, mandatory etc. The different relationship tools are just convenience tools for the same thing.